# How to Move Images a Certain Amount of Pixels Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

I am trying to move images inside of a container using Javascript. Ultimately, I want to move it using setTimeout, but for now trying to do it using an event listener on a button click. It seems to work, but only once. I want to keep moving the images when the button is clicked. Any help is helpful and appreciated.

```
   <div class="images">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"/>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"/>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"/>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"/>
   </div>


</div>

<button id="moveIt">MOVE</button>

<style>

.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 100%;
z-index: 222;
}

.images {
width: 300px !important;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 10px;
height: 400px !important;
}


</style>


<script> 

let images = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
const moveBtn = document.getElementById('moveIt');

let pleaseWork = () => {
   for(i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
   images[i].style.marginLeft = "-300px";
   }
 }
moveBtn.addEventListener('click', pleaseWork);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting margin-left to a static number rather than incrementing it. Here's an example that accesses the current margin-left, strips it of the 'px', converts that to a number, then increments it and applies it back to the element.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
const moveBtn = document.getElementById('moveIt');
let increment = -10
let pleaseWork = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    let ml = Number(images[i].style.marginLeft.replaceAll('px', ''))
    ml += increment
    images[i].style.marginLeft = `${ml}px`;
  }
}
moveBtn.addEventListener('click', pleaseWork);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 222;
}

.images {
  width: 300px !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 400px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
</div>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
</div>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
</div>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596536220655-21429cf12ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
</div>


</div>

<button id="moveIt">MOVE</button>
```